Tensioner adjustment screw for Y-axis
Upon fixing my Ender 3 V3 SE printing mishap, I happened to lose the black tension belt adjustment screw for the y-axis on the print plate bed (little unseen thief creatures are real) and can't find online nor was support any help by sending me to buy on aliexpress.com (did not have it either).
What size and thread is it, to buy aftermarket?
And other parts as well as ALIMARKET takes weeks to come!

I usually get my stuff to Europe in a few days (5-7), the waiting times are rarely that long, but you must spend 10 $ or so. Look for different suppliers! To get an idea, you might want to post a photo of the assembly where the screw is missing!
